# Is there a reason to use "for update skip locked" without a transaction

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

So it seems like there is no reason to use "for update skip locked" without a transaction, but how exactly would it work if I would use this kind of query without a transaction?
Is there a case that you should write them all with "for update skip locked" for them to be transaction friendly just in case?

Use case:

currently need to select entities, check them and after that update them, I want to do it atomically, so the rows selected are locked.
So should I use `for update skip locked` or it doesn't really matter and I rather just wrap whole function with `@Transactional`

also need to say that when I said 'without a transaction', I meant that the function from which the database requests are made is not marked as `@Transactional`

Comment: Records can be locked without using a transaction, like a query that is concurrently running

Comment: so if I want to lock some rows before updating it, using select for update query will still be usefull?

Comment: `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` is very rarely useful, no matter what. I cannot answer your question without knowing what you intend to do.

Comment: Also, there is *always* a transaction.

Comment: As Laurenz said, every query is a transaction. And because of that, it could have an impact on concurrent transactions. But that depends on what, when and where. The statement "there is no reason" depends on your specific use case but you didn't share any information

Comment: added a little bit of context, hoe that's enough

Comment: Postgres is mvcc, uncommitted reads are not a thing, "without a transaction" doesnt happen. Please clarify the question.

Comment: How do you check the records that you selected? If that is done immediately in your code without any additional input from outside, you could do the update without the select.

Comment: added a little more context to the question, also didn't really understand what you mean saying there is always a transaction, transaction with only one request doesn't realy makes sense, 
as said in Postgres docs: The essential point of a transaction is that it bundles multiple steps into a single, all-or-nothing operation.